# Debian Raid5 LVM

Tags: debian, lvm, raid5

I want to setup a debian server mainly used as data storage.
I have 4 devices:

- /dev/sda (160GB) - installed debian on it
- /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc, /dev/sdd (all 500GB) - created a raid5 array with it

Now I am not sure, how to go on. 
Is it usefull to create a LVM on the raid5 /dev/md0?
How can I do this? Is there a good HowTo?

Or can I just create filesystem on the raid5 and create different partitions?

Comment: You have seen the LVM HOWTO?  http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the mdadm raid5 array.
Create a volume group (I used the complete array).
Create LVM2 logical volumes at whatever size you deem necessary.

I used redhat's documentation when building my 8TB NAS on Debian Lenny.

http://www.redhat.com/magazine/009jul05/features/lvm2/

Comment: The LVM2 logical volumes are my partitions then? Or do I need to partitioning them respectively installing a filesystem on them?

Comment: Most likely what you want is for LVM to be directly on top of the /dev/md* device.  So use pvcreate on /dev/md* and pass /dev/md* to vgcreate.  Within the volume group you create your LVs, and on your LVs, you put a filesystem.

Comment: @Zoredache: I was to fast ;) Everything was written in redhat's documentation posted by PG Puters. But thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a server, what will happen if your root device (on /sda) goes down?

It is normal to have at least a RAID1 configuration for your root partition, to help keep the server up should a single disk fail. If uptime isn't an issue perhaps this isn't a consideration. Note that you have to be careful to get grub installed on both disks' boot sectors if you are using software raid for a boot partition.

Raid 5 for your data storage is sensible, although Raid 6 is better! You asked

> Is it usefull to create a LVM on the raid5 /dev/md0?

If you want to use up the whole of the software raid device, it isn't useful to create LVM logical devices. If you think you might want to, for instance, move `/var` off your boot device to a new device created in a logical volume, then yes. Naturally if you are going to do that you should be careful not to use the whole of your md0 device with a single logical volume as then the reason for using lvm is somewhat obviated.

Other important stuff to know about lvm:

- While it is fine to fill up your PV with a VG, don't fill up your VG with LVs if you want flexibility in future (!)
- Choose a filesystem that can expand if you choose to extend an LV (XFS is a good choice)
- Filesystems in general aren't good at contracting to match an LV contraction
- LVM snapshots are best avoided as they have terrible IO.

Check out the tldp [Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO) for some more interesting info.